# New Blender Artist Requires Tips in Regards to Modeling

Tags: modeling

I applied a subdivision surface modifier to the main part of the weapon, and I’d just like some suggestions for how to make the part that is circled which is part of the main part of the weapon.

[image]
[image]

I thought about creating a whole new object, but I’m not sure if that’s a quality thing to do. Some edge loops might do the trick too. What would you guys do?

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)